# Did the Shuttle payload bay have illumination?

Tags: space-shuttle

Were there lights inside the Shuttle cargo bay, either to provide illumination when the doors were closed or to better illuminate cargo when the doors were opened?

Slightly related: [Have optical zoom systems been used in space exploration?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/34309/26446)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There were metal halide floodlights in the payload bay floor and one on the forward bulkhead pointing towards the bay.

Reference: http://science.ksc.nasa.gov/shuttle/technology/sts-newsref/stsref-toc.html#sts-light-exterior

There were generic flight rules about use of the lights and flight-specific rules if the lights were blocked by payloads in the bay.

An example of flight-specific PLB light rules from the STS-88 Flight Requirements Document.

> b.    Payload Bay Light Constraints
>
> 1. For bay-to-earth (+ZLV), biased nose-to-sun (-XSI), and biased tail-to- earth (+XLV) attitudes, operation of the forward and
>    mid payload bay   floodlights (PBFL) is unconstrained (PBFL 1 through 4
>    may be ON     continuously) when either Node 1 is stowed in the bay or
>    attached to   the ODS.  The aft PBFLs (PBFL 5 and 6) are constrained to
>    be OFF        when Node 1 is stowed in the bay, but unconstrained when Node
>    1 is  attached to the ODS.
> 2. In a bay-to-sun attitude (+ZSI), when Node 1 is stowed in bay the   operation of PBFL 1 is unconstrained (may be ON continuously),
>    PBFL  2 is constrained to operate no more than 110 minutes ON,
>    followed by   at least 30 minutes OFF, mid PBFLs (PBFL 3 and 4) are
>    constrained to    operate no more than 240 minutes ON, followed by at
>    least 45 minutes  OFF and the aft PBFLs (PBFL 5 and 6) are constrained
>    to be OFF at  all times.
> 3. In a bay-to-sun attitude (+ZSI), when Node 1 is attached to the ODS,    the operations of all PBFLs (PBFL 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, and 6) are
>    unconstrained.
> 4. While mated to the ISS, operations of all PBFLs (PBFL 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, and    6) is unconstrained.
> 5. These PBFL operational constraints are based on PBFL system     limitations.  No payload constraints have been identified.

Here is a diagram of the PLB lights from the [crew operations manual](https://www.nasa.gov/centers/johnson/pdf/390651main_shuttle_crew_operations_manual.pdf):

[image: schematic diagram of payload bay light locations in the shuttle payload bay]

Here is a video of the payload bay doors being opened during orbital night during STS-81. One of the forward PLBFLs is on, illuminating the scene.

Comment: Thanks for the edit!